# WPF when clicking the (X) to close the new window - how to get the other window to appear?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am doing a project in school and came across a little challenge I can't solve.
I have mulitple classes in C# and making WPF wireframes for those.

How do I get a hidden window from another class to appear when clicking the X-button on the new window?

```
private void Window_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
            mainWindow.ShowDialog();
            mainWindow.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            
        }
```

This is in my class where im closing the window and this is from the class where I hide my window and open the other one

```
private void Button_Administrator_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) //Åbner Admindelen
        {
            this.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            AdminMainMenuWindow adminMainMenuWindow = new AdminMainMenuWindow();
            adminMainMenuWindow.Show();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass the instance of the window you are hinding as a constructor parameter to the new Window you are showing:

**MainWindow**

```
private void Button_Administrator_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
  this.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
  AdminMainMenuWindow adminMainMenuWindow = new AdminMainMenuWindow(this);
  adminMainMenuWindow.Show();
}
```

**AdminMainMenuWindow**

```
public partial class AdminMainMenuWindow: Window {
  Window mainWindow;
  public AdminMainMenuWindow(Window mainWindow) {
    this.mainWindow = mainWindow;
    InitializeComponent();
    Closing += Window_Closing;
  }

  private void Window_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e) {
    mainWindow.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
  }
}
```

Your code is not working because you are changing the visibility of a new instance of MainWindow instead of changing the visibility of the existing one.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response! It helped me to continue with my project!